# ¿Como guardar una imagen en una carpeta de en mi proyecto en nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, express, heroku, multer

Aplique en mi proyecto todo a respecto a Multer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) y logre hacerlo funcionar en localhost :(
Tambien funciona al subirlo al servidor de heroku, sin embargo no lo guarda en el repositorio, y al actualizarlo con otro codigo, pierdo la imagen guardada, como puedo guardarlo en el repositorio de mi proyecto?

````
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './src/storage/avatarcustomer')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })

  const upload = multer({ storage })

  module.exports = upload```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que heroku no almacena imagenes, cada vez que reinicies, se pierde todo, para poder almacenar imagenes debes hacerlo con un servicio externo, por ejemplo AWS S3, me pareció leer que es muy barato (3 centavos por 3 meses fue el cobro que leí) y de esa manera puedes almacenar tus imagenes y manejarlas de manera externa.